# enthought imports: enthought.traits.api vs traits.api

Tags: python, enthought

In the library is traits imported this way:

```
from enthought.traits.api import Int, Float
# and the other bad thing:
from enthought.traits.ui.api import View
```

But I've installed traits via pip (`pip install traits`), and in this version traits are imported this way:

```
from traits.api import Int, Float
# here is
from traitsui.api import View
```

What a mess!

How can I use enthougt.traits etc.? Or how I can create a simple wrapper, so that I get an pseudo-enthought-module?

(I've also tried to `pip install ets`, but not all packages want compile.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install the [etsproxy](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/etsproxy) ([github](https://github.com/enthought/etsproxy)) module for backwards compatibility.

Comment: The linked site has a redirect loop. What's a better source fer `etsproxy`?